# SQL Update Replace statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replace, wildcard

I need to write a sql update statement using REPLACE. The string looks like 'SE*88*000000001'. I need to replace the number between the two asterisks '*'. There is no pattern here other then that number to be replaced is always between two asterisks. Is it possible to use wild cards in this situation?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Might depend on the database system you are using.

Comment: Is there a way we can implement this with regular expressions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
;
WITH RowSetToUpdate AS (
  SELECT
    acolumn,
    Asterisk1Pos = CHARINDEX('*', acolumn),
    Asterisk2Pos = CHARINDEX('*', acolumn, CHARINDEX('*', acolumn) + 1)
  FROM atable
  WHERE acolumn LIKE '%*%*%'
)
UPDATE RowSetToUpdate
SET acolumn = STUFF(
  acolumn,
  Asterisk1Pos + 1,
  Asterisk2Pos - Asterisk1Pos - 1,
  'replacement_string'
)
```

Or if it's a specific number that is to be replaced, then it would be even simpler:

```
UPDATE atable
SET acolumn = REPLACE(acolumn, '*88*', '*replacement_string')
WHERE acolumn LIKE '%*88*%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `PARSENAME` function. Something like:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn =  
      PARSENAME(REPLACE(YourColumn, '*', '.'), 3)
    + '*'
    + 'whatever you want to replace the number with'
    + '*'
    + PARSENAME(REPLACE(YourColumn, '*', '.'), 1)
```

This would work as long as the value never contains periods and only the two *'s around the number.

Comment: Nice idea to use `PARSENAME()`!

Comment: Thanks. I do like your answer though. This might be considered a bit of a hack, but if it works, great.