# Replace numeric values for *'s in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

HI I'm really new to programming (noob), as such I need to change de values from one colum to another in a MySQL database. Here some info: database: *project*, table: *users*, column2: *number1*, column3: *number2*. In *number1* I have numeric data in these two forms: `91234567` or `1000123456` I want to change them to this form: `91aaaa67` or `91 * * * * 67` and `1000aaaa56`or change the a's for *'s and put them in *number2*. The table has several users and the numbers are totally different for each user. This means, that in both cases I want to change the third to sixth digits from right to left in the numbers from column2 (*number1*) and store them in column3 (*number2*). I have tried the following code:

```
UPDATE users SET number2 = REPLACE( number2,  '91234567',  '91****67' )
```

I tried the code from Andriy M in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525184/sql-update-replace-statement)  But it doesn't work for me, there are erros that appear regarding the RowSetToUpdate function and I think it's beacuase it is for SQL not MySQL.

So I don't know how to do it and make it automated, I also have a php document with forms that fill the database correctly. I just want to add this function to the database!!! I use phpmyadmin on a windows environment, php 5.4.7, mysql 5.5.27.

I hope you can help me, and thank you in advance!!!

Comment: This will only work if your fields are strings. It won't work if they are defined as integers, because anything containing a * is not an integer. Also, REPLACE operates on strings.

Comment: I have those columns as varchar, Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do it like this

```
UPDATE users SET number2= CONCAT(LEFT(number1,2),'aaaa',RIGHT(number1,2)) WHERE LENGTH(number1) =8
```

and

```
UPDATE users SET number2= CONCAT(LEFT(number1,4),'aaaa',RIGHT(number1,2)) WHERE LENGTH(number1) =10
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This works great!!! I have another question, how can I do to make this run in a lapse of time, it can be 30 minutes or one hour. It should be done in php or it can be done in MySQL? Thank you in advance!!! Sorry I can't vote up yet :(

Comment: what do you mean "run in a lapse of time"  You want the query to automatically run every 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes sir!!! Sorry for my English!!! I was trying to say that!!! How can I set the query to run every 30 minutes? :D

Comment: well, you should google it or search around here on StackOverflow for "how to run php script every hour"  or something like that.  I've seen it done where they schedule a task in windows to run every 30 minutes, and that runs a console command that just executes http://...yourscript.php  There are several options though.

Comment: Thank you again!!! I'll do that and then when I have solved this I'll post the final solution!!! :D

Comment: If you know php in a web, I recommend you to create a php script to do this and call through an curl or wget command from command line. Then you could call this from a .bat script in windows or a shell script in linux. The third and last step is to program it to be called every 30 minutes with the windows task manager or the linux cron. Further reading of these topics is needed if you are novice to these.

Comment: @RaulLuna  i agree. In my case I have windows task manager running a cron every 15 mins, which runs a .bat with wget, which calls a mycrons.php.  Then in my db I have a cron table where I can schedule tasks for any time, and they they run with a resolution of 15 min. That way I can programmatically schedule tasks as needed, set number of repeats, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE users 
SET number2 = concat(left(number2, 2), '****', right(number2, 2))
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/24166)

Comment: It works but only for one number, in the example the only number that changed was 91234567 the others didn't!!! Thank you!!! :D

Comment: Thank you [juergen d] (http://stackoverflow.com/users/575376/juergen-d) your new answer works very good too!!!